# RANK used in 'where' returns invalid column, but exists in results set

Tags: postgresql

I basically have a table with `date`, `timestamp`, `DID`, `coordinates`.

I want a query that will return rows with the last coordinate from day X, and the first coord from day X+1, and the coordinates. So it will only return results where there are 2 consecutive dates.

This is what I came up with. Been trying to get this query to work, it's almost perfect, but I just need to add the commented out `where` conditions and it'll do exactly what I want. But when I uncomment, I get an error "column doesn't exist":

```
SELECT  a.timestamp_intersecting_date d1,b.timestamp_intersecting_date d2,   
        a."DID", 
        a.timestamp_intersecting_max t1, b.timestamp_intersecting_min t2,
        RANK () OVER ( 
          PARTITION BY a.timestamp_intersecting_date
          ORDER BY a.timestamp_intersecting_max DESC
       ) timestamp_d1_rank ,
        RANK () OVER ( 
          PARTITION BY b.timestamp_intersecting_date
          ORDER BY b.timestamp_intersecting_max ASC
       ) timestamp_d2_rank,
        a.coords_centroid, b.coords_centroid
FROM
    signals a
INNER JOIN signals b ON (a."DID" = b."DID")
WHERE (b.timestamp_intersecting_date = a.timestamp_intersecting_date + INTERVAL '1 DAY')
AND a."DID" = b."DID"
--AND timestamp_d1_rank = 1
--AND timestamp_d2_rank = 1
ORDER BY a."DID", t1 desc, t2 asc
```

How to solve this?

Comment: Yes, you can’t refer to them in the where clause as window functions are evaluated *after* the where clause. You can put your query into a with clause, or wrap it as a subquery.

Comment: Please *always* provide a table definition as `CREATE TABLE` statement showing exact data types and constraints. And your version of Postgres. Helps to avoid misunderstandings and makes it so much easier to help. You have  a timestamp *and* a date?  `timestamp_intersecting_date`? A lot can go wrong right here already ...

Comment: Data distribution matters *a lot* here. If each `DID` has a (at most) a single row per day, you would use a different query than when there can be *many*. If time zones are involved, the definition of "day" may need some attention.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot use window/ranking functions or their aliases in the `WHERE` clause because they are evaluated in `SELECT`, after the `WHERE` has been evaluated.

You can use a subquery (derived table or CTE) to process a second `WHERE` clause, after the window functions have been evaluated:

```
SELECT d1, d2,
       "DID",
       t1, t2,
       coords_centroid_a,
       coords_centroid_b
FROM
  (
    SELECT  a.timestamp_intersecting_date d1, b.timestamp_intersecting_date d2,   
            a."DID", 
            a.timestamp_intersecting_max t1, b.timestamp_intersecting_min t2,
            RANK () OVER ( 
              PARTITION BY a.timestamp_intersecting_date
              ORDER BY a.timestamp_intersecting_max DESC
           ) timestamp_d1_rank ,
            RANK () OVER ( 
              PARTITION BY b.timestamp_intersecting_date
              ORDER BY b.timestamp_intersecting_max ASC
           ) timestamp_d2_rank,
            a.coords_centroid AS coords_centroid_a, 
            b.coords_centroid AS coords_centroid_b
    FROM
        signals a
    INNER JOIN signals b ON (a."DID" = b."DID")
    WHERE (b.timestamp_intersecting_date = a.timestamp_intersecting_date + INTERVAL '1 DAY')
    AND a."DID" = b."DID"
  ) AS t
WHERE t.timestamp_d1_rank = 1
  AND t.timestamp_d2_rank = 1
ORDER BY "DID", t1 DESC, t2 ASC ;
```

Comment: thanks, that worked...i tried something similar but using WITH t AS ( slect ..., what you put in th from statement) select t.*, from t then joins where ranks=1/2, it was forcing me to add the columsn to group by or use aggregates, it ended up looking like this, mind telling me my mess up ? thanks https://pastebin.com/5aN3E29k

Comment: Ah, you have both `GROUP BY a."DID"` to get MAX/MIN and window functions there. There are ways that that's valid but it's usually complicated.

Comment: If my query above solved the issue, use it. You cab use a CTE of course but that may result in different performance, as Postgres materializes CTE results (at least in versions less than 12).

Answer (score 5):

You cannot use aliases in `WHERE` clauses, nor can you use Window functions.

To demonstrate, consider this example ([fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=99769f0d8bac2fca610700e2065bb99d)).

```
CREATE TABLE payment (amount INTEGER, pay_date DATE);

INSERT INTO payment VALUES (54,  '2019-09-01'), (56,  '2019-09-01'), (154, '2019-09-02'), 
(156, '2019-09-02'), (254, '2019-09-03'), (256, '2019-09-03');
```

Then run the two following queries:

```
SELECT 
  *, 
  SUM(amount) OVER (PARTITION BY pay_date) AS the_sums
FROM payment
WHERE the_sums > 200; -- ERROR:  column "the_sums" does not exist
```

and

```
SELECT 
  *, 
  SUM(amount) OVER (PARTITION BY pay_date) AS the_sums
FROM payment
WHERE SUM(amount) OVER (PARTITION BY pay_date) > 200;
-- ERROR:  window functions are not allowed in WHERE
```

You didn't post your error message or PostgreSQL version, but your problem is that `timestamp_d1_rank` and `timestamp_d2_rank` are aliases.

You have two options:

- First Option: use the aliases/Window functions within a subquery (also in fiddle)

```
SELECT * FROM
(
SELECT 
  *, 
  SUM(amount) OVER (PARTITION BY pay_date) AS the_sums
FROM payment
) AS tab
WHERE the_sums < 200;
```

Result:

```
amount    pay_date  the_sums
    54  2019-09-01       110
    56  2019-09-01       110
```

- Second Option: you can use a [`CTE`](http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-cte/) (aka the `WITH` clause as outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8095413/470530) or as in @ypercubeᵀᴹ 's answer above or also see the fiddle.

For a good explanation of this whole area, see [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/225883/34007).

Answer (score 3):

The confusion with syntax rules concerning input and output column names has been addressed properly by existing answers. This is about a lurking performance problem.

There is an transient `CROSS JOIN` in your query that **scales *terribly*** with growing number of rows per `("DID", date_col)`. Example: If a `"DID"` has 100 coordinates per day, the query ends up processing 10.000 (!) combinations with the next day.

Based on this assumed table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE signals (
   "DID" serial PRIMARY KEY
 , date_col date NOT NULL  -- ?
 , time_col time NOT NULL  -- ?
 , coords_centroid geography  -- ?
);
```

And assuming there are only *few* rows per `("DID", date_col)`, this query should be *much* faster already:

```
SELECT a."DID", a.date_col, t1, coords1, t2, coords2
FROM  (  -- first row per ("DID", date_col)
   SELECT DISTINCT ON ("DID", date_col)
          "DID", date_col, time_col AS t2, coords_centroid AS coords2
   FROM   signals
   ORDER  BY "DID", date_col, time_col
   ) b
CROSS JOIN LATERAL (  -- corresponding last row from previous day
   SELECT "DID", date_col, time_col AS t1, coords_centroid AS coords1
   FROM   signals a
   WHERE  a."DID" = b."DID"
   AND    a.date_col = b.date_col - 1
   ORDER  BY time_col DESC
   ) a;
```

Needs an index on `("DID", date_col, time_col)`.

More might be done here, depending on your actual setup and actual data distribution. I'll elaborate if you are interested and provide missing information ...